# I'm trying to call a function from an external javascript file in my html that changes classes of some divs and it just doesn't react

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the js file

```
function changeClass(Id,Val){
    document.getElementById(Id).class = Val;
}

function show(){
    changeClass('resize','bS resize');
    changeClass('main','mS main');
    changeClass('sidebar','ad a sS sidebar');
    
    changeClass('title','b tS title');
    changeClass('topbar','bd b tpS topbar');
    changeClass('footer','bd b fS footer');
    
    document.getElementById('resize').onclick = 'hide()';
}

function hide(){
    changeClass('resize','bH resize');
    changeClass('main','mH main');
    changeClass('sidebar','ad a sH sidebar');
    
    changeClass('title','b tH title');
    changeClass('topbar','bd b tpH topbar');
    changeClass('footer','bd b fH footer');
    
    document.getElementById('resize').onclick = 'show()';
}
```

And here's the part of html that should be able to call the hide and show functions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
    
    <head>
        
        <meta charset = "utf8">
        <title> RVJade's comprehensive genetics </title>    

        
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "styleColor.css">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "hideshow.css">
        
        
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "resize.js"> </script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <button type="button" class = "bS resize" id = "resize" onclick = "hide()">
            <img src = "out.png" class = "iS"></img>
            <img src = "in.png" class = "iH"></img>
        </button>...
```

it simply does nothing, I tried to add the js script to the html file but that doesn't do anything either

I want it to change the classes of html elements with ids: resize, main, topbar, title and footer, so the style changes, and change the onclick attribute of the button so it has the show function instead, so when it's clicked again the changes are reversed.

Comment: `document.getElementById('resize').onclick = 'show()';` - that should be `document.getElementById('resize').onclick = show;` - the same for `hide`

Comment: You also have the possibility of using `classList.toggle` to toggle an elements class. The function though uses `document.getElementById(Id).class` - that should probably be `document.getElementById(Id).className`

Comment: an `img` is a `self-closing` element - you do not need, and indeed it is incorrect, to add `</img>`

Answer (score 0):

If you were to apply a dataset attribute to each element that you wish to change that contains the alternative css class names the toggling between styles could easily be done like this.

```js
// find all elements that have the data-altclass attribute
let col=document.querySelectorAll('[data-altclass]');

// assign the click handler to the button
let bttn=document.getElementById('resize');
    bttn.addEventListener('click',e=>{
      // iterate through the collection of elements found above
      // and toggle the class & data-altclass attributes
      col.forEach(n=>{
        n.dataset.tmp=n.className;
        n.className=n.dataset.altclass;
        n.dataset.altclass=n.dataset.tmp;
        n.removeAttribute('data-tmp');
      });
    });
```

```css
/* CSS rules for illustration of effect only */
.sS,.tpS,.tS,.bS,.fS{
  color:red;
}
.tH,.mH,.bH,.fH,.mH{
  color:blue
}

button{
  border:2px solid black;
  padding:1rem;
  background:silver;
}
```

```html
<div id='sidebar' class='ad a sS sidebar' data-altclass='ad a sH sidebar'>#SIDEBAR#</div>
<div id='topbar' class='bd b tpS topbar' data-altclass='bd b tpH topbar'>#TOPBAR#</div>

<h1 id='title' class='b tS title' data-altclass='b tH title'>#TITLE#</h1>

<main id='main' class='mS main' data-altclass='mH main'>
  
  

  <button type="button" class="bS resize" id="resize" data-altclass='bH resize'>
      <img src="out.png" class="iS" />
      <img src="in.png" class="iH" />
  </button>


</main>

<footer id='footer' class='bd b fS footer' data-altclass='bd b fH footer'>#FOOTER#</footer>
```